# In phpMyAdmin Edit Index dialog, the SQL statement is "lost" after save

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The greatest strength of phpMyAdmin (IMHO) is that it seemed to strike the perfect balance between GUI comfort and raw coding of SQL. 
I am currently on version 4.1.13, and recent versions have tended to try to introduce a few jQuery UI effects and AJAX.

Now I am having serious trouble with this scenario:

To **edit an index**, a UI dialog is called up. After save, all is well, but the problem is, **the SQL statement(s) invoked is flashed for only a fraction of a second, then `slideUp`ed out of view**.

If you're like me, you sometimes want to copy out this SQL code, to be run on another schema, or for whatever reason.

I thought I could find a setting to turn off some of these UI effects, but naah!

So, is there a way I can turn off the sliding away of the last used SQL? Even a hack would be okay for me right now.

Thank you.

Comment: Version 4.1.13 is outdated, please try the latest stable one on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net

Comment: Well, upgrading to v4.3.10, revealed that there is now a **Preview SQL** button on this jQuery dialog. (I'm happy someone noticed that quagmire and provided this useful button in the latter version). Therefore, upgrading is indeed a perfect solution to the indicated problem, and @Marc, your comment deserves to be marked correct! Or would you rather have me "answer" it? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 4.1.13 is outdated, please try the latest stable version.